# How can I use CLI to start a service on multiple remote PCs?

Tags: command-line

Due to the constraints of my environment, I am unable to use Powershell to start this service and need to use CLI. I need to be able to start a single service on apporx. 100 workstations.

I have been able to start the service remotely on a single PC, but I would like for it to point to a txt list of computers.

This is the command that will work on a single workstation

```
sc \\remotepc start [service]
```

I have tried this command but does not start the service on the remote workstation

```
for /f %H in (D:\Server\workstationlist.txt) do net start [service]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a few ways to execute these commands

```
for /f %i in (computerlist.txt) do sc \\%i start winrm
```

computerlist.txt is a text file containing the names of the remote computers with one name per line. You can also replace this with a comma-separated list of computer names.

```
For /f "tokens=1" %i in ("Computer1,Computer2,Computer3") do sc \\%i start winrm
```

Where 'Tokens=1' tells the for loop to split the list into separate tokens based on the comma character and use only the first token as the computer name